# this.props.router.push doesn't reload the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So, I have this two components in my react-route config file:

```
<Route path="/questions/:test_id" component={QuestionsComponent}>
   <Route path="/questionnew/:test_id" component={QuestionModalNewComponent} />       
</Route>
```

They are independent Components and not the Parent-Child kind. *QuestionModalNewComponent* (as the name suggest) shows a Modal "window" to add a question, after the user clicks on "Save" the new question is saved and then I call:

```
this.props.router.push('/questions/'+this.props.routeParams.test_id);
```

Because now I need that all the questions (including that one that I just created) show in the screen. However react-router doesn't "reload" *QuestionsComponent*.

I'm guessing that since *QuestionModalNewComponent* is nested in the *QuestionsComponent* **<Route>** element, that is the reason that prevents that *QuestionsComponent* is "executed" again.

Is there a way to reload a React Component?

**UPDATE**

According to this thread:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1982

React-router is not designed to work this way, the reload data should be handled by react component lifecycle methods: componentWillMount , componentDidMount, etc. So I moved the Modal screen to the parent Component. Thx guys!

Comment: Sure it's not updating? Try overriding `shouldComponentUpdate()`

Comment: if they're not parent / child, why is your route nested?

Comment: Are nested because on this way react-route loads the nested component in the same screen.

Comment: if you adding a route for creating new question you are supposed to have a separate route like `<Route path="/questions/new" component={QuestionNew} />  ` . if you want a modal to appear in `<QuestionsComponent />` you don't need adding route.

Comment: where you call `this.props.router.push('/questions/'+this.props.routeParams.test_id)`?